# Migrating symbols from ArcGIS Server to CartoDB

Tags: arcgis-server, carto, mxd, cartocss

We decided to migrate to CartoDB after many years of using ArcGIS Server.
We already handled data migration and now we are looking for an easy to export our symbol rules defined in a MXD to CartoCSS.
Is there any tool available to ease this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can import your layers from ArcGIS Server into CARTO as datasets with [The ArcGIS Connector](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/import-api/the-arcgis-connector/) or as shapefiles, **but the styles associated with these layers will be lost**. You will need to style them using the user interface or the CartoCSS tab.

Comment: I was afraid to see this answer but I guess there is nothing to do about it